# Nodejs Sequelize Attributes Get data inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgres database which look like this :

[image]

I want to query those data and return only some of it. Below is the function that I wrote.

**citizenController.js**

```html
exports.getAllCitizen = async (req, res) => {
  const { page, size } = req.query;
  //Check if theres a NIK filter
  const nik = req.query.nik;
  const condition = nik ? { nik: { [Op.iLike]: `%${nik}%` } } : null;

  //Pagination
  const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);

  try {
    const response = await Penduduk.findAndCountAll({
      where: condition,
      attributes: ["id", "nik", "profil_penduduk"],
      limit,
      offset,
    });
    const data = getPagingData(response, page, limit);

    return res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Here is the response from function above :

[image]

The problem is, I don't want to return all of the **profil_penduduk** object data, I just want to get the **nama , alamat, and status_warga** from it.

[image]

How can I achieve that ? I tried to do like :

```
attributes: ["id", "nik", "profil_penduduk.nama","profil_penduduk.alamat","profil_penduduk.status_warga"]
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get the details of reference table to use `include` as

````
const response = await Penduduk.findAndCountAll({
      where: condition,
      attributes: ["id", "nik"],
      include: [
        {
          model: profil_penduduk, // name of reference table
          attributes: ['nama' , 'alamat', 'status_warga'],
        }
      ],
      limit,
      offset,
    });
    ```
````

Comment: Hello, thanks for checking out. But the problem is profil_penduduk is not a referenced able, its a column inside citizen table.